# Applying rules or ACL when user has 2 roles

Tags: php, acl

I have a user based system. When user has 1 role my system works well. I have no clue how do i take into consideration when user should have multiple roles. How do i check rule when applying for a page.?

Comment: I suggest you add another method to your code.

Comment: In other words: what answer do you expect here?

Comment: @Robin v. G. - Like how should be the scenario handled when user has multiple roles.

Comment: `if ($user->hasRole('ROLE_A') && $user->hasRole('ROLE_B'))`...?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you move away from `$user->hasRole(foo)`. It makes it difficult to change role permissions dynamically. You could as the ACL system questions like `$this->acl->isAllowed($user, 'edit_page')`. If the ACL system checks the roles this user has, and one of the roles grants permission to do a certain action, it can return this permission.